# Does turning up volume in post production reduce quality?

Tags: post-production, volume

I want to turn down my sensitivity really low then in post production I turn up the volume to reduce background noise, would this degrade quality?

Comment: I'm not sure of your premise here. If you record at very low input then amplify in post, you will bring up the noise floor as well as any background noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality will not be degraded, however the noise of your mic and setup will also increase. Answer is no to your question, but it introduces other problems if not handled well. Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle sound issues is to do things the other way round - have your gain up as high as you can without any distortion for input, this reduces the noise floor by minimising the effect of noise throughout the amp (it will be a smaller percentage of the sound). Then set your output volume as needed.

Comment: how does it reduce the noise floor?